# Работа с bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Начал изучать Bootstrap, вроде пока все понятно, но появился один вопрос.
Если делать только на Bootstrap, то получается не очень красиво, а вопрос в том, как изменять стандартные стили?
То есть вот так:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="navbar">
  <nav class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a>Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a>Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a>Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a>Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a>Ссылка</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Получается стандартное меню. Как можно изменить цвета и прочее?

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: Еще бы разобраться там с параметрами)

Comment: а добавить после bootstrap.css свой файл стилей с переопределёнными селекторами?

Comment: Там переписывать много надо будет

Comment: @alexfedosienko, эм, а кто-то должен переписать за вас? Или как?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А в чём собственно проблема? Создаёшь файлик `style.css` в нём инклудишь сам файл `bootstrap.css` и всё, дальше просто описываешь классы, какие надо изменяешь (все так и делают) а стандартные шаблоны - это как опора, от чего вы будите отталкиваться.

Comment: Спасибо, думал можно как то иначе сделать